# How to change text color in search bar in iOS 13?

Tags: swift, ios13

I am just about to port my UIKit app to iOS 13 and got stuck when trying to change the text color in my search bar to look nice in dark mode. I have tried already all proposed solutions and code snippets here on stackoverflow.

Is it a bug in iOS 13 that changing the search bar text color (even by using the new attribute searchTextField) does not work yet? Or does anybody have a working example for iOS 13 to share?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by myself - sorry, was my fault :-)

I had the following line of code in `AppDelegate` which I had overseen:

`UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = convertToNSAttributedStringKeyDictionary([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.black])`

After changing the color to `UIColor.label` it works fine in light mode and dark mode :-)